# Delete all ID's that don't have a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I want to delete all the ids and there rows that do not have a specific value. For example say I have a table of houses and the have a primary key called house_id and I have another table called house_attributes that looks something like this.

```
#   house_id     Pet      Pet_Name   ...
1   1            cat      tigger
2   1            bird     tweety      
3   1            dog      rover
4   2            cat      Whiskers
5   2            bird     Polly
6   3            cat      Sylvester
7   3            bird     Juno
8   3            dog      Rex
```

From this table what is the best way to delete all house_ids that do not have a pet dog. So from the example above house_id 2 would meet that criteria so any instance of house_id 2 would be deleted from the table.

Thank you

Comment: As per your above example house_id of Pet = dog is 1, so except dog do you want other house_id = 1 to get deleted?

Comment: from the example i would want rows with house_id of 2 to be deleted cause house_id does not have a dog. So basically anything to do with house_id 2 is gone. So no more Whiskers or Polly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this maybe helpful :

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE  house_id NOT IN(SELECT house_id
                       FROM   yourtable
                       WHERE  Pet = 'dog')
```

the subquery will retrun those `house_id` which have pet `dog` and `not in` clause will ensure that delete except these.

Note: if you want to delete from both `houses` and `house_attributes` then same query should be run on `houses` table first then on `house_attributes`.

Comment: While "not in" constructs are simple and intuitive, they tend to be slow.  Be careful about using them.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of construct will help.

```
delete from houses
where house_id in
(select house_id
from houses
except
select house_id
from pets
where pet = 'dog'
)
```

However, it's a strange plan.  Once those records are gone you can't use them anymore.  Another option is to keep your records and simply select the ones that do have pet dogs.